# Migration from Play 2.4.1 to 2.5.6 - Sockets

Tags: java, playframework, websocket, akka, akka-stream

I have updated my Play Framework version from **2.4.1** to **2.5.6** but now I have a problem with the web sockets management.

I have a Controller class where method `liveUpdate()` return a `WebSocket<String>` instance.
In this method I use `WebSocket.whenReady()` using `Out<String>` in a `HashMap<Out<String>, String>` where the key is the client output stream and the value is a `String` that contains the language information because when I need to send a broadcast message I iterate the `HashMap`.

Now all this is removed or deprecated in **2.5.6**!
Searching the web I found that the new implementation is based on **Akka Streams** using the `Flow` class but I have no idea how to adapt my code.

- `WebSocket.whenReady()` is replaced by `WebSocket.Text.accept()`
- `Out<?>` is replaced by akka stream with `Flow` class

This is my code:

> **Alarms.java**

```
public class Alarms extends Controller {

    @Inject
    private ActiveAlarms activeAlarms;

    [...]

    public WebSocket liveUpdate() {

        return WebSocket.whenReady((in, out) -> {

            in.onMessage(language ->{
                activeAlarms.register(out, language);
            });

            in.onClose(() -> activeAlarms.unregister(out));
        });
    }

    [...]
}
```

> **ActiveAlarms.java**

```
public class ActiveAlarms{

    private HashMap<Out<String>, String> websockets = new HashMap<>();

    [...]

    public void register(Out<String> out, String language) {
        websockets.put(out, language);
        updateWebsockets(out, language);
    }

    public void unregister(Out<String> out) {
        websockets.remove(out);
    }

    private void updateWebsockets(Out<String> s, String lang){

        if(s == null) return;

        List<AlarmEvent> alarmsList = AlarmEvent.findActive();
        ArrayList<AlarmEvent> translatedAlarmsList = new ArrayList<>();

        //translate
        alarmsList.forEach(e ->{
            if(e != null) {

                e.setAlarm(e.getAlarm().translate(checkLanguage(lang)));
                translatedAlarmsList.add(e);
            }
        });


        //WRITE TO SOCKET
        String alarms = Json.stringify(Json.toJson(translatedAlarmsList));
        try {
            s.write(alarms);
        } catch (Exception e2) {
            Logger.debug("EX ActiveAlarms --> updateWebSocket  " + e2.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private void updateWebsockets(){
        websockets.forEach(this::updateWebsockets);
    }

    [...]
}
```

Any idea on how to convert my code to the new implementation of `WebSocket` ?

Answer (score -3):

I think you can easily migrate from one to the other. Did you check [this documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets)?

If you want to manage the Socket with Akka streams, this is the corresponding [documentation part](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaWebSockets#Handling-WebSockets-using-Akka-streams-directly).

Let me know if you still need help to migrate, I'll help you.